# Rails 'bundle install' fails because attempt to write to file 'is unsupported by your OS'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm attempting to run a rails app on my local machine developed elsewhere, but I can't get it to run locally. When I run `rails s` to get the server running, I get:

```
Could not find proper version of railties (4.2.6) in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

So, naturally, I run `bundle install` but get the error:

```
Attempting to write to
`/home/rails/apps/intranet/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0` is
unsupported by your OS
```

My OS is macOS Sierra version 10.12.4.

Also, railties is in the gem folder and seems to be the correct version.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Adding Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

gem 'devise'
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'where-or'

# Railties
gem 'railties', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.6'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'guard', require: false
  gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
  gem 'guard-bundler', require: false
  gem "guard-cucumber", require: false
  gem 'ruby_gntp'
  gem 'terminal-notifier'
  gem 'terminal-notifier-guard'
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  gem 'capistrano3-unicorn'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem "cucumber-rails", require: false
end
```

Comment: Can you post your `Gemfile`?

Comment: @jdgray It has been added. I took a look at the file, and whoever first developed it didn't have the Railties line, so I added it in. Either way I'm still getting the same result that says writing to the file is unsupported by my OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out what was the issue. Since this was downloaded from a remote server, the .bundle/config file had a different path for 'BUNDLE_PATH'. I simply had to change that to the path on my own computer instead of the path on the remote server and I stopped getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have write permissions to the directory `` /home/rails/apps/intranet/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0` ``

Comment: I have Read & Write permissions to that folder, so that doesn't seem to be the issue.